# create a list with the given number of strings

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, racket, typed-racket

I am trying to create a list with a given number of strings. So, if I enter (make-row 3) it will be '("ivy" "ivy" "ivy") and if I enter (make-row 2) it will be '("ivy" "ivy).

I currently have the following code but it doesn't work:

```
(define (make-row a)
  (cond
    ((= 0 a) '())
    (else
    (list "ivory")
    (make-row (- a 1)))))
```

Can you please tell me how to write this code or what I doing wrong? I am learning how to program with Typed/Racket at home so don't have access to teachers or mentors :(

Answer (score 1):

Just use one of the built-in procedures:

```
(define (make-row a)
  (make-list a "ivory"))
```

But if you want to do it from scratch, use the standard template for building an output list by `cons`ing the results. Notice that your code won't work because of that `(list "ivory")` in the middle of nowhere - only the last expression of a condition is returned, and anyway that's not how we recursively build a list. Try this:

```
(define (make-row a)
  (cond ((= 0 a) '())
        (else (cons "ivory" (make-row (- a 1))))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(make-row 3)
=> '("ivory" "ivory" "ivory")
```